# py2exe setup.py suddenly not working

Tags: python, py2exe, setup.py

I'm pretty sure i didn't modify anything in my setup.py but my program is not building into an exe anymore, the errors i'm getting when running "python setup.py" are:

- Unknown distribution option: "windows"
- error: invalid command "py2exe"

I tried reinstalling python 3.4.3 / py2exe 0.9.2.2
My script is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import sys

sys.argv.append('py2exe')
setup(windows=['Gui.py'],
  data_files=[('Drivers', ['Drivers/chromedriver.exe', 'Drivers/IEDriverServer.exe']),
              ('', ['webdriver.xpi']),
              ('', ['webdriver_prefs.json'])]
  )
```

when i run python setup.py --help-command, py2exe is not listed there maybe that's the reason i cant use it?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

i must have deleted a required line by error, when i add:

```
import py2exe
```

it works
stupid mistake on my side